# WPF Error with loading window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf window and on start i fill one listview with a background worker thread. I want to put a loading window while the thread excecuted. So i create another wpf windows with a progress bar. When i call the worker.RunWorkerAsync() the listview fills normally. BUT if i create a new loading window i can't see my basic wpf window. If i close loading window i see my basic wpf window, but the listview is empty.

My Loading window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Loading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Loading..." Height="100" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="pb" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="350" Height="20" IsIndeterminate="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></ProgressBar>
</Grid>
```

I call the loading window:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
Loading l = new Loading();
l.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Do you still see the problem if you use `l.Show()` instead of `ShowDialog`?

Comment: Take a look at the busybox control. It may help

Comment: No difference with Show(). Ιf put the l.ShowDialog(); previous of worker i the thread don't runs until i exit from loading window..